# i want to copy data from one sheet another sheet only select rows with checkbox In Google App Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I want to copy srange data in drange on check box validation. below only print data in logger.log but not in drange.

```
function insertrow(){
   var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(); 
   var full = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Source"); 
   var shed = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Destination");
   var lr = full.getLastRow();
   var srange = full.getRange(2,2,lr,2).getValues();
   var dlr = shed.getLastRow();
   var drange = shed.getRange(dlr+1,1);

   

   srange.forEach (function(row){ 
    if(row[0]){
      Logger.log((JSON.stringify(row)));
      
    }
   })
   }
```

Comment: Your question makes no sense.

Comment: i want to copy only the selected checkbox row @MikeSteelson

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
function insertrow() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var full = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Source");
  var shed = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Destination");
  var lr = full.getLastRow();
  var srange = full.getRange(2, 1, lr, 3).getValues().filter(r => r[0]==true);
  var dlr = shed.getLastRow();
  shed.getRange(dlr + 1, 1,srange.length,3).setValues(srange);
}
```